# How to install Ruby gem ffi 1.8.1 on the M1 of the MacOS system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, apple-m1, ffi

My Rails application needs the dependency of ffi 1.8.1 when it starts, but I am a MacOS M1 chip, and I have tried many methods, but I can't solve this problem.
I tried many methods, and finally used `arch - x86_ 64 gem install ffi - v 1.8.1 -- with flags="- Wno error=implicit-function-declaration"` can be installed, but when I execute 'rails' to start the application, the following error will occur:

```
dlopen(/Users/steverogers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/ffi-1.8.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/steverogers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/ffi-1.8.1/lib/ffi_ c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/steverogers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/ffi-1.8.1/lib/ffi_ c.bundle' (no such file), '/Users/steverogers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/ffi-1.8.1/lib/ffi_ c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')) - /Users/steverogers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/ffi-1.8.1/lib/ffi_ c.bundle (LoadError)
```

It roughly means that the arm version is required, but I installed x86_ 64 version, how can I solve this problem?

I want to resolve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can update ffi to version 1.15.5 for ruby ​​2.7.7 in your project. This works well for Mac M1. Just run `gem ffi install` and add this version to your gemfile. Then run `bundle install`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved the problem of installing 1.8.1, but when I started the program, a new problem appeared:in `block in ffi_lib': Could not open library 'sodium': dlopen(sodium, 0x0005): tried: 'sodium' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSsodium' (no such file), '/usr/lib/sodium' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'sodium' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/sodium' (no such file), '/usr/lib/sodium' (no such file, not in dyld cache).I have installed libsodium using homebrew and configured environment variables for the lib package, but I still can't

Comment: @peterparker Have you tried [this](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/880#issuecomment-1344752085) for your version?

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying issue is `x86_64` vs `arm64`, the issue might be resolvable by doing a Universal Binary install of the needed gems.

Currently, `ARCHFLAGS` can be used to create a univeral binary install of `ffi` with the system Ruby shipped by Apple.

```bash
sudo env ARCHFLAGS='-arch arm64 -arch arm64e -arch x86_64' \
  gem install ffi

## verify that universal binaries were installed:
CHECK_DIR="/Library/Ruby"
find "$CHECK_DIR" -name "*.bundle" | xargs file

# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/ffi_c.bundle: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64] [arm64:Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64e]
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c/ffi_c.bundle: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64] [arm64:Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64e]
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64] [arm64:Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64e]
```

The `ffi` install was tested on both an Apple Intel mini and an Apple Silicon mini. Each had a clean macOS Ventura 13.4 install with Xcode 14.3.1 (14E300c) on the boot drive.

The Apple Intel mini can create a universal binary with multiple Instruction Set Architecture (ISA) slices. However, the Intel can only run and test the native `x86_64`. The Apple Silicon mini with Rosetta enabled can run|test all of the `arm64`, `arm64e`, and `x86_64` ISA binary slices.

Tested configurations:

- Apple Intel mini, macOS Ventura 13.4 (22F66), Xcode CLI Tools  14.3.1 (14E300c)
- Apple Silicon M1 mini, macOS Ventura 13.4 (22F66), Xcode CLI Tools  14.3.1 (14E300c)

---

Caveat: If homebrew has `libffi` installed, then `/opt/homebrew/bin` needs to be excluded from the `$PATH` environment during execution of `gem install ffi`.

```bash
brew info libffi
# ==> libffi: stable 3.4.4 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]
# Portable Foreign Function Interface library
# https://sourceware.org/libffi/
# /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libffi/3.4.4 (17 files, 724.8KB)
#   Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on …
```